# SQL query DATEDIFF returning NULL

Tags: mysql, datediff

I am writing this query in the mySQL DB. The table `listing` has two columns `StartDate` & `EndDate`. I want to return the `Duration` ie number of days between these two dates using `DATEDIFF`. My query is:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(StartDate, EndDate) as 'Duration' FROM listing;
```

The table returns NULL in the Duration column.

And if I write,

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, EndDate) as 'Duration' FROM listing;
```

returns

```
Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'   0.000 sec
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what are two values if startdate and enddate?

Comment: What are the data types of those columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that `DATEDIFF()` expects the dates to be in the format `YYYYMMDD` and the column inputs of `StartDate` and `EndDate` that I was giving was `MMDDYYYY`. I changed it to `YYYYMMDD` and it worked. So, the following expression with the dates in YYYYMMDD format works just fine.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(StartDate, EndDate) as 'Duration' FROM listing;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two parameters is correct.  If you are getting NULL it's probably because the values in those columns aren't date or datetime types.

From the MySql docs:

```
DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)
DATEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.

mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 23:59:59','2007-12-30');
    -> 1
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2010-11-30 23:59:59','2010-12-31');
    -> -31
```

Comment: Hey Brad, the problem was with the format of the date I was giving. It should be YYYYMMDD and I was giving MMDDYYYY. I changed it and it worked.